# How to select a particular hashmap<String,String> from a list by its value

Tags: java, list, hashmap

I'm fairly new to Java and have been searching everywhere for an answer.

I run a sql query and use the response to build a list of hashmaps from the column name and values.

```
List<HashMap<String,String>> rulesList = Sql.getStuff("abc");
```

This gets me a list like this {column_1=abc, column_3=ghi, column_2=def}

I want to do two things with this list. First off I want to see if any column contains a particular value (ruleName).  This part decent enough.

```
if (rulesList.get(0).containsValue(ruleName)) {
    System.out.println("Expected: " + ruleName);
    System.out.println("Actual: " + ruleName); //Would like to change this to include the actual column name and result
```

Then I want to check all the other columns that have a particular phrase in their name to see if they contain a value or not, such as the word "column" from "column_1, column_2, column_3".  If they do contain the value then I want to print out the column name and value.

However, this is when I run into the problem of not knowing how to select from within the list.  How can I get only column_2 and its accompanying data, or the column name associated with value abc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this example?

```
       List<HashMap<String,String>> rulesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>() {{
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("key", Integer.toString(i));
                map.put("column1", "Value in Column1 in row " + i);
                map.put("column2", "Value in Column2 in row " + i);
                add(map);
            }
        }};

        for (HashMap<String,String> row : rulesList) {
            for (String columnName : row.keySet()) {
                // look for a column name
                if(columnName.contains("column")) {
                     System.out.printf("Column \"%s\" has a value of \"%s\"%n", columnName, row.get(columnName));
                }
                // look for a cell value
                if(row.get(columnName).matches(".+Column\\d in row 1")) {
                    System.out.printf("Value found in %s, row %s%n", columnName, row.get("key"));
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need vocabulary : a [hashmap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) associates a **key** (unique) with one **value**.

So with that keywords in mind you can easily find answer, like :

> First off I want to see if any column contains a particular value (ruleName)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17249524/hashmap-contains-key) is an example

> Then I want to check all the other columns that have a particular phrase in their name to see if ...

And [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538011/hashmap-containsvalue-whats-the-point).

Comment: Thanks Totem.  Without these details I wouldn't have been able to understand SlumpA's answer.  Using both of your guys answers I was able to work out a solution to my problem.

Comment: Glad to help, don't forget to mark your problem as solved.

Answer (score 0):

your question is premised around a list of hashmaps

Based on your question, it looks like you might be trying to use this structure:

```
List_Row<HashMap<String_ColumnName, String_Value>>
```

If this is the case, consider modifying your storage structure and storing a hashmap each with a list:

```
HashMap_ColumnName<ArrayList<String_Values>>
```

then you can simply grab a column and look through data.  to get the row back as a list, you can write a function to do that pretty easily

```
getRow(i) {
    HashMap<String,String> row = new HashMap<String,String>()
    for(k:results) {
        row.put(k, results.get(k).get(i))
    }
return row
}
```